# Cypher relating distant nodes and displaying the merged relationship

Tags: cypher

I can display two nodes which relate through other nodes.
In this case a `Person` `created` an `object` `during` a `project.

I can match this using the following:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[]-()-[]-(Project)
WHERE p.name = "Bob"
RETURN p, Project
```

However, no relationship is displayed in Neo4J's browser between the two, obviously there is no direct relationship, I do not want to add one, but they are related via another node. So adding a relationship visually only, not actually explicitly stating it in the data.

Take the following:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[]-()-[]-(Project)
RETURN p, Project
```

No single person is identified, no single project, how would I know who was involved in which project, and I display a coded relationship, condense/merge relationships in between?

Comment: Could you add more detail to your question, what do you mean by "display"?

Comment: I've added that I want to display/visualise the relationship in Neo4J. The relationship is via an intermediary node, So I want to visualise `(a)-[r1]-(b)-[r2]-(c)` as `(a)-[r?]-(c)`. Like `(Person)-----[pseudo-relationship]-----(Project)` The `pseudo-relationship` is a merger of the `-[r1]-(b)-[r2]-`. I hope that makes the question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your project node is identifiable through a label and/or properties, this is one way.

```
MATCH (p:Person {name: 'Bob'})
MATCH (project:Project)
MATCH path=(p)-[*]-(project)
RETURN path LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an improvement, but it still displays the intermediately node. 
It shows `(Person)-[createrof]-(3DModel)-[collectedduring]-(Project)` rather than `(Person)-[psuedo-relationship]-(Project)`.

Comment: Now I'm somewhat confused what your goal is. Is pseudo-relationship an actual relationship? Do you seek the shortest path and a visualization of all nodes and relationships within that path?

Comment: Technically Person - [partof] - Project is true but not specified, it should be inferred because if a `Person - created - 3Dmodel` and the `3Dmodel - was_part_of - Project`, then that `Person - was_part_of - Project`, but I have not specified that relationship. I could be explicit, but I'm wanting to see if cypher can 'infer' relationships in this way?

Comment: in my posted solution, you're not explicitly stating the relationship(s) between the two nodes and how many hops there are. That's what the `[*]` is for. The idea is to get your start and end node (for performance) and then return the first path (`LIMIT 1`) between those nodes.